# ¿Cómo hacer un input siempre negativo?

Tags: javascript, html

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que un input de tipo number permita solo números negativos o el número que se ingrese se convierta en negativo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si no tienes que soportar Internet Explorer 8, podrías escuchar el evento [input](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event) y en él podrías identificar si se trata de un número positivo para multiplicarlo por `-1` en esos casos:

```js
const input = document.getElementById('myNegativeNumber');

const check = () => {
  if (!input.validity.valid) input.value = 0;
  if (+input.value > 0) input.value *= -1;
};

input.addEventListener('input', check);
input.addEventListener('blur', check);
```

```html
<input type="number" id="myNegativeNumber" value="0" />
```

**Edición:** Sería bueno chequear que el valor del `input` es válido (y también hacer los chequeos en el evento [blur](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Events/blur)), para que si se escribe o se pega un carácter alfabético (Firefox sigue permitiendo hacerlo) o una cadena inválida que no represente un número, se restablezca el valor por uno numérico, en este caso `0` (ya he realizado el cambio en el código).

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="number" value="0" id="negative-counter" max="0">
</body>

<script>
    var counter = document.querySelector('#negative-counter');

    counter.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
        checkForAllowValues(event);
    });
    counter.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        checkForAllowValues(event);
    });

    function checkForAllowValues(event)
    {
        console.log('checkForAllowValues()'); // HACK:

        if (event.target.value > 0) {
            event.target.value = 0;
        }
    }
</script>
</html>
```

#### Explicación

Se puede controlar usando javascript, mediante la subscripción a eventos que no se introducen números mayores que 0 directamente, o usando la tecla de *flecha arriba* (evento `keyup`) o que no se aumente el valor usando los botones del propio input (evento `click`), si bien este último se puede evitar estableciendo el atributo `max` del input (esto también afecta la pulsación de las flechas en el teclado).

Para optimizar, se puede establecer el atributo `max`y controlar el evento `keyup`.

Answer (score 0):

Usa los atributos `min` y `max` para validar el rango de números que deseas permitir:

```html
<input type="number" max="-1">
```

Comment: Eso no previene que se ingrese a mano un número positivo, solo si se ingresa haciendo uso del slider del input.

Para evitar el ingreso manual no veo otra que agregar un evento al blur del input e informar o alterar el valor ingresado.

Comment: Ok, las dos cosas sería la combinación perfecta.

Comment: Puedes capturar el keyDown y ahí tambien comprobar que el dígito tecleado tenga el signo negativo delante, y así no esperar a salir del input para validar. Cuidado que un input number se puede escribir valores como 45--34+45--4