# ¿Cómo hacer para no elegir valores negativos en un input number?

Tags: html

Tengo un `input type="number"`¿cómo hago para que no me deje seleccionar números negativos? O sea, que si presiono la flecha hacia abajo, solo me permita como mínimo el número `0` y no que siga contando `-1`, `-2`, `-3` y así sucesivamente.

```html
<form action="../../form-result.php" method="post" target="_blank">

  <p>Tu edad: <input type="number" name="edad"> <input type="submit" value="Enviar datos"></p>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Situar la propiedad `min` en `0`, evitará que introduzcas números negativos usando los controles nativos, pero no impedirá que escribas de manera manual o copies y pegues un número negativo en el input. Esto lo puedes lograr añadiendo un pequeño chequeo en `JavaScript`. Hace un tiempo respondí [una pregunta similar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/300755/c%c3%b3mo-hacer-un-input-siempre-negativo/300790#300790), pero lo que buscaba el OP era totalmente lo contrario. Usando el mismo código, lo adapto a tu caso para que solo acepte números positivos:

```js
const input = document.getElementById('edad');

const check = () => {
  if (!input.validity.valid) input.value = 0;
  if (+input.value < 0) input.value = 0;
};

input.addEventListener('input', check);
input.addEventListener('blur', check);
```

```html
<form action="../../form-result.php" method="post" target="_blank">

  <p>Tu edad: <input id="edad" type="number" name="edad"> <input type="submit" value="Enviar datos"></p>

</form>
```

Answer (score 4):

Establece el atributo `min="0"`, que hace exactamente lo que necesitas, limita el `input` al valor mínimo que le configures.

```html
<form action="../../form-result.php" method="post" target="_blank">

  <p>Tu edad: <input type="number" name="edad" min="0"> <input type="submit" value="Enviar datos"></p>

</form>
```

Comment: Excelente muchas gracias, me funciono.

Comment: No especifica nada, punto abajo

Answer (score 3):

basta con agregar `min="0"`

```
<form action="../../form-result.php" method="post" target="_blank">

<p>
   Tu edad: 
   <input min="0" type="number" name="edad"> 
   <input type="submit" value="Enviar datos">
</p>

</form>
```